# Android Studio Documentation is always showing

Tags: android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSvnV.gif)

When I press `ctrl+q`, the documentation is always shown.
I want the documentation to be auto hidden
How can I do this? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep pressing ctr + q to cycle between different views for the documentation window. You'll get the one you want eventually.

Comment: I want that  when I mouse press other space the documentation window can close    How can I do  Thank you

Comment: @Android Just to clarify, you want the documentation window to close when you press elsewhere on the screen, right? To do that press Ctrl + q once (the documentation window will open), keep pressing them until you get a window that is a small rectangle. That should do what you want.

Comment: OK Thank You very much.

Comment: I want to konw what's the differences of the two kinds of rectangular  thank you

Comment: @Android As far as I know, they are just different views. Apart from the "click-to-dismiss" feature I'm not sure if there's any other difference.

Comment: @Android Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-Q toggles between doc window states (when using the default keymap).
Possible states:

-Hidden

-Shown to the side of the auto-complete list

-Docked as one of the tabs

If you have a different keymap, you can search for this action in Settings -> Keymap. The action is called "Quick Doc".

Once the auto-completion window is open, you can cycle through the states of the documentation window by pressing Ctrl+Q. The last doc window state will be remembered for next time the auto-completion window opens.